# Is dependent => :destroy required with embeds_many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

If one has: `embeds_many :foos`.

Is `:dependent => :destroy` required? Or, if I destroy the parent element. all respective `foos` will be removed automatically?

I tried to check `Foo` on console, but get:

```
Mongoid::Errors::InvalidCollection: Access to the collection for Foo is not allowed since it is an embedded document, please access a collection from the root document.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Embedded docs can not be accessed directly. They are contained in the parent doc and can only be accessed through parent. When you destroy a parent document, embedded documents get removed along with it, but if you have any callbacks specific to destroying of embedded docs you should take a look at [cascade_callbaks](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/pull/845).

Comment: Take a look at this: http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/v3/relations.html. He's using dependent: has_many :albums, dependent: :delete, belongs_to :label, dependent: :nullify. If it automatically destroys embedded docs, then why have a dependent delete and nullify? There is nothing to nullify.

Comment: Because has_many and belongs_to are not embedded relations, they are referential relations storing only key on belongs to side.